# How do I get the text from a dynamically created textarea using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Ok so I have this:

```
$('a[name=writecommentsmodal]').live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var date=new Date();
    var currdate=date.getYear()+" "+date.getMonth+" "+date.getDate();
    var comm=new addComment("",fullname,currdate,$  ***("#inputspace2").text()) ***;
    comm.appendComment($(".wallpostcontainer"));
});
```

And I'm trying to get the text from inputspace2. inputspace2 is dynamically created when button is pushed (that button is 'a[name=writecommentsmodal]'). That button also happens to be dynamically created from a different button click (hence the use of live), but I digress. That inputspace2.text is empty when I click on the modal button. How do I access it? In firebug its "". I'm thinking maybe having to use live again but I'm no

Answer (score 2):

For text areas, use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

Using `textContent`, `innerText`, `outerHTML` or `innerHTML` on a textarea returns the contents of the text field as defined in the HTML. User's modifications of the content are only visible through the `.value` property.

Comment: @FloydPink Only the `value` property is updated when the user modifies the contents of a textarea. **See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rANgJ/2/)**

Comment: I checked that after I saw your detailed answer and you're right - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/rANgJ/1/
Thanks...